# $scope.$on not updating controller property AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have an Angular/Ionic app that uses the Network Phonegap API to check for network connection. I have defined event handlers to handle online/offline events. When these events occur, I broadcast events through the `$rootScope` `$broadcast` method. In my controller, I listen for this event using the `$on` method and update a scope property. The scope property is bound to the view to disable a button when there is no internet connection. The problem is the scope property is not set even when the offline/online events are fired (Tested on my Samsung S3).
My code for clarity:

```
document.addEventListener("offline", function() {
    //broadcast offline event to controllers
    $rootScope.$broadcast("networkStatusChange", 'Offline');
}, false);

document.addEventListener("online", function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast("networkStatusChange", 'Online');
}, false);
```

My CONTROLLER

```
$scope.$on('networkStatusChange', function(event, status) {
    $scope.networkInfo.isOffline = status === 'Offline' ? true : false;
});

$scope.networkInfo = {}; //bound to view to disable button is isOffline is true
```

MY VIEW

```
<p class="error" ng-show="networkInfo.isOffline">No Internet Connection.</p>
```

I don't know why the `networkInfo.isOffline` property is not changing when I switch on/off my phone's internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must make sure that is call by other function in your addEventListener function.
there is example for you [test demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/K13DJ5Np0bIGAlShXJC3/)

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you need to call `$scope.$apply()` in your sub function:

```
$scope.$on('networkStatusChange', function(event, status) {
    $scope.networkInfo.isOffline = status === 'Offline' ? true : false;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```